# Search and highlight rows in Excel 2010

Tags: search, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a macro shortcut to search for a word in my Excel file, which consists of a large amount of rows and columns. Is there any way that I can search for the word that I wanted and then allow the program to highlight the entire row for me?

[image: example]

For example when I search "b", it will highlight the entire row like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim rng, cel As Range
Dim search_item

Set rng = Selection
search_item = InputBox("Find what?", "Test")

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value = search_item Then
        cel.EntireRow.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Hope this gets you started.

**Update:**
You mentioned that you search large rows.
Might as well use this:

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim arr() As Variant 'i do not know your data type
Dim search_item As Variant 'i do not know your data type, change to your liking
Dim lrow, lcol As Long
Dim found As Boolean

Set rng = Selection
lrow = rng.Rows.Count
lcol = rng.Columns.Count

ReDim arr(1 To lrow, 1 To lcol)
arr = rng.Value

search_item = InputBox("Find what?", "Test")

For i = 1 To lrow
    For j = 1 To lcol
        If arr(i, j) = search_item Then
            rng.Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Select
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If found Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

Both code does what you want.
It searches on the currently selected range.
Second code is faster when searching on large selections.
Also both finds EXACT match only.

Comment: there's an error when i run it, i change both the arr() and search item into string, and when i debug it, arr = rng.Value was empty. Why is that so? Thanks.